# ES6 Promise - Why does throw from catch() and throw from then() not behave the same way?

Tags: promise, es6-promise

I have this piece of ES6 code that invokes a java backend. The java backend normally returns status code 200 and a json payload, but sometimes status code 500 and a json payload. For 200 I want to deserialize the json and pass the resulting object up the promise chain. For 500 I want to deserialize the json and *throw* the resulting object up the promise chain, i.e. have it hit the catch blocks.

The following code does almost what I want:

```
invoke(className, methodName, args) {
    return this.httpClient
        .fetch('/api/' + className + "/" + methodName,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                body: json(args)
            })
        .catch(response => {
            // Function A
            throw response.json();
        })
        .then(response => {
            // Function B
            return response.json();
        });
}

this.invoke("TestService", "testMethod", {a: 1, b: 2})
    .then(response => {
        // Function C
        console.log(response); // prints the actual json object which I expect
    }).catch(response => {
        // Function D
        console.log(response); // prints: [object Promise]
    });
```

- Function A gets invoked for 500. Good.
- Function B gets invoked for 200. Good.
- response.json() returns a promise of a deserialized object in both A and B. Good.
- Function A causes function D to be invoked. Good.
- Function B causes function C to be invoked. Good.
- The argument, response, to function C is the deserialized object. Good.
- **But**, the argument, response, in function D is not the deserialized object, but a promise of a deserialized object.

I've been working at this for a while now, but I'm having trouble explaining to google what my problem is.

**Question:** Why does returning a promise 'unwrap' the promise for the next function, but throwing a promise passes the promise itself into the next function?

Is there any way I can achieve what I want, which is for function D to get the 'unwrapped' object just like function C?

Comment: Eeeck gad. Throwing a promise?  What is the real world reason to ever do that?  You throw a reject reason, not a future async operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get the promise in `catch` callback, is that this is by specification.

For *returned* values within a `then` or `catch` callback, the rule is that that promise must resolve before the outer promise resolves, and that the resolved value should be the value promised by the returned promise. From the [Promises/A+ specs 2.2.7.1](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-41):

> If either `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` returns a value `x`, run the Promise Resolution Procedure `[[Resolve]](promise2, x)`.

Chapter 3 in that specification further explains what that means.

However, this is not true for *thrown exceptions*, as can be seen in [point 2.2.7.2](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-42):

> If either `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` throws an exception `e`, promise2 must be rejected with `e` as the reason.

No attempt is made to recognise `e` as a promise nor to wait for its resolution. It is thrown as is, and that will be what you get in the next `catch`.

#### Solution

The solution is thus to *return* a promise, but a promise that will throw the resolved value (not a promise):

```
return response.json().then(data => { throw data });
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you.  The solution works great :)